# Add custom css class on an anchor tag in codeigniter 3.1.6

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination, codeigniter-3

I am using codeIgniter 3.1.6.
I am using the pagination and trying to put a class in anchor tag.
Right now my link is looking as follows

```
 <ul class="pagination float-right">
         <li class="prev">
            <a href="http://localhost/app/role/index/1" data-ci-pagination-page="2" rel="prev">Previous
           </a>
         </li>
    </ul>
```

But i want to put a class in anchor tag which should look like as below

```
<ul class="pagination float-right">
         <li class="prev">
            <a class="myClass" href="http://localhost/app/role/index/1" data-ci-pagination-page="2" rel="prev">Previous
           </a>
         </li>
    </ul>
```

I want to override the default create_link() function of the default pagination library.
If there is any other way please help me with the same.
Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you want to archive? unclear bit

Comment: You can customise the links - read up on the config settings in https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/pagination.html#customizing-the-pagination

Comment: Just to point out barbecue you want to go to the index function of role you don't need to include index function in the url because its the default function `http://localhost/app/role/1` or `<?php echo base_url('role/1');?>`

Comment: @wolfgang1983 It isn't clear if rerouting is used for this route, therefore `base_url('role/1') !== base_url('role/index/1')` It could escalate with another issue before this one is solved.

Comment: @AbdullaNilam I have updated the question, can you review it?
Thanks

Comment: You still have not explained why you want to put that class there in the first place. Do you want to put it only onto this specific link, the "prev" link that links back to the previous page? If you want to style that link individually, you can do so via CSS already, by selecting it via its relation to its ancestors, `.pagination .prev a { color: red; }` or something like that.

Comment: No I don't want to put on only this link, I want to put this class on every anchor tag. I can put it even from javascript after the loading the page but I wanted to know if putting a class on an anchor tag can be don via codeigniter or not, as we can do on current anchor tag by putting 
`$config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class=" page-item active"><a class="page-link" href="#">';`
I wanted to know if there is any custom configuration to put a class on every anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

$config['data_page_attr'] = 'class="myClass"';

This will add class to anchor. 
This is not the correct way but class will be added.

Answer (score 0):

In 2020 ci 3.x

Following code adds class page-link to every item except current.

```
$config['data_page_attr'] = 'class="page-link" ';
```

Add this also

```
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="page-link">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
```